# loginWithExternalService not working on multiple drones

Tags: javascript, meteor

loginWithFacebook and loginWithTwitter are returning errors sometimes when my app is hosted on multiple drones/instances behind a load balancer.

The user clicks on the login button, a popup window appears (and asks the user to login if necessary) then disappears, without actually logging the user in or setting Meteor.user().

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, (err) ->
   console.log Meteor.user() //returns undefined
   if err
      console.log err //return Accounts.LoginCancelledError error with no message
      handleError(err)
)
```

**I'm running a Meteor app on nodejitsu with 2 drones, with a mongoDB backend at MongoHQ (I'm using sandbox, so no oplogging for now). The above error never reproduces when I run locally.**

The issue seems to be that the callback from Facebook does not hit the application instance that is waiting for a response, but another instance.

Sticky sessions are enabled on the load balancer and the rest of the application is working fine.

Has anyone experienced this? Is this a bug in Meteor? Is this something that can be dealt with by the hosting provider?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the callback from facebook comes back on your other drone and its session isn't accessible on the other drone (which is the one waiting for the request).

You could avoid this if you use sticky sessions. If you could configure your load balancer this way it should work.

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but double checked with nodejitsu, and they are using sticky sessions: https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/features/#feature/sticky-sessions
All the other parts of the application seem to work well with 2 drones, it's just the login functionality that's broken.

Comment: Does the request sent from the app to Facebook actually keep track of what application instance is running so that Facebook's response hits that instance?